# Getting UITableViewCell from its superview iOS 7 issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I have few UI objects in the cell that have got gesture recognizer instance. I need to get cell where pressing object is located. I have the method below for getting it, but it just work before iOS 7:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender view] superview]superview];
```

for iOS 6 it return `UITableViewCell`

for iOS 7 it return `UITableViewCellScrollView`

I think the new cell has some additional views in iOS 7, that's why I grab `UITableViewCellScrollView` instead of `UITableViewCell` as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, relying on the view hierarchy is not a good approach - Apple can break it at any time.

You should use a delegate protocol to connect your cell to the controller.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to get a table view cell from it's subview is to convert the subview's location to a location in the table view, then ask the table view for the index path of the cell at that point:

```
CGPoint subviewPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:subviewPosition];
```

Then, you can get the cell for that index path:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Where should I put those lines? the first in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and the second in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I got it. All the lines at the same place, there where I used to have [[[sender view] superview]superview];

Answer (score 2):

```
CGPoint subviewPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:subviewPosition];
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *path=[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```