# The Application crashes at replaceobjectatindex

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

The application crashes at replaceobjectatindex . 
The clickedbuttonpath.row returns nil value . Need help .

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{ 
if (textField.text.length>0)
 { 
UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
 NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [addSizesTableView_ indexPathForCell:clickedCell]; 
if (textField.tag==6) 
{ 
[textDic setObject:textField.text forKey:clickedButtonPath]; 
[orderArr replaceObjectAtIndex:clickedButtonPath.row withObject:textField.text];
```

---

This is the crash log which am getting .

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d1ef35 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001062acbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c25998 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 968
    3   BookMyStock                         0x0000000103559ac0 -[AddSizesOfColors textFieldDidEndEditing:] + 368
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000105289549 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 382
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104ccc4f5 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 236
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001052892d4 -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 114
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105295953 -[UIView(UITextField) endEditing:] + 173
    8   BookMyStock                         0x0000000103557c2d -[AddSizesOfColors addTFTotheView] + 285
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104b568be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5d410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104c5c7df -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104b9c308 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104b9cc33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104b699b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104b76a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104b52103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c54551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c4a41d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c49a54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c49486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108bdc9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104b55420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  BookMyStock                         0x0000000103492913 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107c7e145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: r u checkd the which index u get

Comment: please post a crashlog, otherwise no one will be able to help you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please refer to the Help Center on how to ask a question with good chances of being answered (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, include error messages that would allow better undestanding of the issue.

Comment: This code works fine with ios 7 but crashes in ios 8 .

Answer (score 0):

[[textField superview] superview] returns nil, incase of iOS 8, whereas in iOS 7 it returns some value. As suggested in below link, don't rely on view hierarchy.

You can check this link [Getting UITableViewCell from its superview iOS 7 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100557/getting-uitableviewcell-from-its-superview-ios-7-issue)

You can try below like structure

```
CGPoint subviewPosition = [textField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath* clickedButtonPath = [addSizesTableView_ indexPathForRowAtPoint:subviewPosition];
```

Comment: Thanks Vinoth . I tried your code but the problem is that the application is crashing at
 [orderArr replaceObjectAtIndex:clickedButtonPath.row withObject:textField.text];

Comment: Can you keep a breakpoint or NSLog and see clickedCell is getting a non nil value in iOS 8.? Because if clickedCell is nil, then clickedButtonPath will be nil, then clickedButtonPath.row will be nil.

Comment: UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];

Comment: clickedCell is not giving a nil value .